# O que é que negamos em "ele não se calou porque a Joana o confrontou"?

Tags: significado, ambiguidades

Dizemos que ele não se calou e que a causa disso foi a Joana tê-lo confrontado?

> (a) Ele só não se calou porque a Joana o confrontou.

Ou dizemos que ele calou-se, mas a causa disso não foi a Joana tê-lo confrontado?

> (b) Não foi porque a Joana o confrontou que ele se calou.

As duas interpretações são possíveis e a frase é irremediavelmente ambígua? Faz diferença se dissermos:

> (c) Ele não se calou por a Joana o ter confrontado?

E se projetarmos a ação para o futuro, as coisas ficam mais claras?

> (d) Ele não se vai calar por a Joana o confrontar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É ambígua, sim, sem contexto é difícil perceber o significado. Consideremos a frase sem "não":

> (1) Ele calou-se porque a Joana o confontrou.

Não há aqui qualquer dúvida: (a) ele calou-se e (b) o motivo por se ter calado foi a Joana o ter confrontado.

Ao adicionar "não" , a ambiguidade é que surge é: estamos a negar (a) ou estamos a negar (b). Se estivermos a negar (a), estamos ainda a afirmar (b) (modificado por "o motivo por se **não** ter calado"), porque "não" cobre apenas a primeira oração.

Se estivermos a negar (b), ainda há uma ambiguidade lógica extra (ou mais exatamente, o facto que a afirmação avança é muito limitado): como o "não" cobre toda a frase, não estamos sequer a afirmar (a), portanto ficamos sem saber se ele se calou e até se foi confrontado. Esta interpretação é equivalente a:

> Não é verdade que (ele se tenha calado porque a Joana o confontrou).

Portanto ele pode não se ter calado de todo (apesar de ter sido possivelmente, mas não necessariamente, confrontado), ou pode ter-se calado, mas não porque a Joana o confrontou (quer porque tenha acontecido mas não foi a causa, ou porque a confrontação não aconteceu de todo). Basicamente apenas podemos ter a certeza que o não aconteceu foi aquilo afirmado por (1).

Adicionar partículas como "só", "lá" desfaz a ambiguidade, mas altera o sentido da frase:

> (2) Ele só não se calou porque a Joana o confrontou.
>   (3) Ele não se calou lá porque a Joana o confontrou.

Em nenhuma das frases ele se terá calado. Outra hipótese mais neutra é alterar a a ordem:

> (4) Porque a Joana o confrontou, ele não se calou.

Para a desfazer a ambiguidade nos outros sentidos:

> (5) Ele calou-se, mas não porque a Joana o confrontou [não é a causa, possivelmente porque nem aconteceu].

Em relação às últimas perguntas, não creio que reescrever a frase com uma oração reduzida introduzida por "por" faça muita diferença.

Projetar para o futuro já faz alguma diferença -- não existe a questão de a Joana o ter confrontado ou não, porque ainda não acontenceu; a afirmação é apenas prospetiva. Mas de resto a frase continua ambígua.

Comment: Nem me tinha lembrado da possibilidade de a Joana não o ter confrontado.

Answer (score 0):

**"Ele não se calou porque a Joana o confrontou."**

A frase original é certamente **ambígua**.  Em Inglês, assim como em Português, temos muitos exemplos semelhantes: **"She didn't go to the party because Mary was there."**  A ambiguidade pode ser diminuída usando-se intonação apropriada e também uma vírgula após "calou".

Aqui, uma tentativa (talvez inútil) de demonstrar os dois significados:

> - "Ele não se CALOU, porque a Joana o CONFRONTOU." (com uma boa pausa entre "calou" e "porque", significando ele teria se calado caso a Joana não o tivesse confrontado)
> - "Ele não se CALOU PORQUE A Joana o confrontou." (ele se calou por outro motivo)

A intonação correta acaba muitas vezes com a ambiguidade de uma frase. Na língua escrita, no entanto, não dispomos desse recurso.